# How to set multiple commands into a menu item in tools menu?

Tags: c#, plugins, menu, vsix, extensibility

I am trying to add a menu item in the **Tools** menu (using `IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS`) which is having two child menu buttons. But not able to do it. But if I add the same with `IDG_VS_MM_TOOLSADDINS` as a top-level menu then I am able to see it inside **Extensions** menu which is fine (Follow img-1).

[image: img-1]
img-1

As per the image, I want to add *My Top Menu* (with its sub commands) into **Tools** menu.
How can I do that? I tried following code but nothing changes but *My Top Menu* also removed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CommandTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005-10-18/CommandTable" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <Extern href="stdidcmd.h"/>

  <Extern href="vsshlids.h"/>

  <Commands package="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackage">
    <Groups>
      <Group guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroupTop" priority="0x0600">

      </Group>
    </Groups>

    <Menus>
      <Menu guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" type="Menu" priority="0x0600">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>My Top Menu</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Menu>
    </Menus>

    <Buttons>
      <Button guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="Command1Id" type="Button">
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Changed 2</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
      <Button guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="Command2Id" type="Button">
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Command 2</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
    </Buttons>

    <Bitmaps>
      <Bitmap guid="guidImages" href="Resources\Ext1.png" usedList="bmpPic1, bmpPic2, bmpPicSearch, bmpPicX, bmpPicArrows, bmpPicStrikethrough"/>
    </Bitmaps>

  </Commands>

  <CommandPlacements>

    <CommandPlacement guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroupTop" priority="0x0601">
      <Parent guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup"/>
    </CommandPlacement>

    <CommandPlacement guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="Command1Id" priority="0x0601" >
      <Parent guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroupTop"/>
    </CommandPlacement>
    <CommandPlacement guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="Command2Id" priority="0x0602" >
      <Parent guid="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroupTop"/>
    </CommandPlacement>
  </CommandPlacements>

  <Symbols>
    <GuidSymbol name="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackage" value="{5f20b1ae-835b-423f-89e1-a33f2e20a715}" />

    <GuidSymbol name="guidMultipleMenuCmdTestPackageCmdSet" value="{2e60374a-c4f8-4d96-9bb6-301ab412846f}">
      <IDSymbol name="MyMenuGroup" value="0x1020" />
      <IDSymbol name="MyMenuGroupTop" value="0x1021" />
      <IDSymbol name="Command1Id" value="0x0101" />
      <IDSymbol name="Command2Id" value="0x0102" />
    </GuidSymbol>

    <GuidSymbol name="guidImages" value="{512d3770-bde4-4353-a6c0-7138bbfffebe}" >
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic1" value="1" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic2" value="2" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicSearch" value="3" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicX" value="4" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicArrows" value="5" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicStrikethrough" value="6" />
    </GuidSymbol>
  </Symbols>
</CommandTable>
```

**More Information (Edited):-**

When I replace `<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>` from **Menu tag** to **Group tag** and then run, I can see the **sub commands** only under **Tools** menu. (Please reffer to img-2)

[image: img-2]
img-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842795/why-isnt-my-vspackages-context-menu-showing#30198909) answer. Here I got the clue to solving my problem. I just added another group and made few changes as I required to add reference to the group. Following is the code that provided me a perfect solution :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CommandTable xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005-10-18/CommandTable" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <Extern href="stdidcmd.h"/>

  <Extern href="vsshlids.h"/>

  <Commands package="guidCodeReviewMainPackage">

    <Groups>
      <Group guid="guidCodeReviewMainPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_MENU_TOOLS"/>
      </Group>
      <Group guid="guidCodeReviewMainPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuSubGroup" priority="0x0600">
        <Parent guid="guidCodeReviewMainPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuItem"/>
      </Group>
    </Groups>

    <Menus>
      <Menu guid="guidCodeReviewMainPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuItem" type="Menu" priority="0x0600">
        <Parent guid="guidCodeReviewMainPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup"/>
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Caladrius</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Menu>
    </Menus>

    <Buttons>
      <Button guid="guidCodeReviewMainPackageCmdSet" id="Ext1Id" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidCodeReviewMainPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuSubGroup" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Select Directories</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>

      <Button guid="guidCodeReviewMainPackageCmdSet" id="Ext2Id" priority="0x0101" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="guidCodeReviewMainPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuSubGroup" />
        <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic1" />
        <Strings>
          <ButtonText>Load Recent</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
      </Button>
    </Buttons>

    <Bitmaps>
      <Bitmap guid="guidImages" href="Resources\Ext1.png" usedList="bmpPic1, bmpPic2, bmpPicSearch, bmpPicX, bmpPicArrows, bmpPicStrikethrough"/>
    </Bitmaps>
  </Commands>

  <Symbols>
    <GuidSymbol name="guidCodeReviewMainPackage" value="{-----}" />

    <GuidSymbol name="guidCodeReviewMainPackageCmdSet" value="{-----}">
      <IDSymbol name="MyMenuGroup" value="0x1021" />
      <IDSymbol name="MyMenuItem" value="0x1020" />
      <IDSymbol name="MyMenuSubGroup" value="0x1022" />
      <IDSymbol name="Ext1Id" value="0x0100" />
      <IDSymbol name="Ext2Id" value="0x0101" />
    </GuidSymbol>

    <GuidSymbol name="guidImages" value="{a0eaa6e3-70cc-45c8-9300-1bedd0871fe6}" >
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic1" value="1" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPic2" value="2" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicSearch" value="3" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicX" value="4" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicArrows" value="5" />
      <IDSymbol name="bmpPicStrikethrough" value="6" />
    </GuidSymbol>
  </Symbols>
</CommandTable>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the new behavior of Visual Studio 2019. You can't insert custom options anymore outside of the **Extensions** section of that menu. If you build your extension for VS 2015 and 2017 too, then you can add your new options in the **Tools** section or you can create a new entry in the top menu near **Tools**.

Keep in mind that the **Extension** section doesn't exist in VS 2015 and 2017

Comment: I edited the question (by More Information (Edited)). Please go through this again.