# Append item to Add menu of solution- or project node in Solution Explorer

Tags: .net, visual-studio-extensions, vsx, vspackage, vsct

How can I add a sub menu for the Add menu item when right click on a visual studio solution explorer?

I have to add a single sub menu item which will be displayed n right clicking the visual studio solution and move to the Add option in that menu.

I am trying using .vsct (vs package). Please help me with valuable suggestions

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course, there are similiar questions, but this seems to be a special case...

In general, you need to know the menu´s command- and package id that you want to extend. I usually do this by enabling the `EnableVSIPLogging` option in the registry as described by this article: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dr._ex/archive/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1.aspx. The `EnableVSIPLogging` option was introduced with Visual Studio 2005, but still works in any newer version.

Once the `EnableVSIPLogging` option is enabled, you can display the wanted information by clicking on a menu item (or any other UI element that is interconnected with a command) while pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. This will show a message box containing the package guid and command/menu id; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copies the shown menu- or command- data to the clipboard, btw. If you´re interested in menu data (in case it´s a context menu, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> before hovering the item).

This is what I got on my machine...

```
---------------------------
VSDebug Message
---------------------------
Menu data:
Guid = {D309F791-903F-11D0-9EFC-00A0C911004F}
GuidID = 4
CmdID = 850
Type = 0x00000100
Flags = 0x00000000
NameLoc = A&dd
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

The menu information can than be used in authoring your `VSCT` file; this question might be of your interest: [Using vsx how do you create a sub menu with commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642524/using-vsx-how-do-you-create-a-sub-menu-with-commands)

While reading the other question´s answer, you may wonder how these guys figured the names for the command guids... those names are defined by the `vsshlids.h` header file, which is included with the Visual Studio SDK. So, for the guid shown above we find...

```
// Guid for Shell's group and menu ids
DEFINE_GUID (guidSHLMainMenu,
    0xd309f791, 0x903f, 0x11d0, 0x9e, 0xfc, 0x00, 0xa0, 0xc9, 0x11, 0x00, 0x4f);
```

We can use `guidSHLMainMenu` for the group definition...

```
<Group guid="your-command-set" id="your-group-id">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="..." />
</Group>
```

I expected to find a `IDM_VS_CTXT_` constant (or something similiar) in `vsshlids.h` that matches the command id, but nope... Instead I found `cmdidShellWindowNavigate7` and `cmdidShellWindowNavigate5` constants in `stdidcmd.h`; and just tried them out...

First I created new id-symbols for two command groups...

```
<IDSymbol name="grpIdProjectContextAdd" value="0x1080" />
<IDSymbol name="grpIdSolutionContextAdd" value="0x1081" />
```

And a command...

```
<IDSymbol name="cmdIdAddItemHelloWorld" value="0x1082" />
```

Than I defined new groups; and used the obtained command identifiers as parent...

```
<Groups>
    <Group guid="your-command-set" id="grpIdProjectContextAdd">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="cmdidShellWindowNavigate7" />
    </Group>
    <Group guid="your-command-set" id="grpIdSolutionContextAdd">
        <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="cmdidShellWindowNavigate5" />
    </Group>
</Groups>
```

Of course, I need a button (which is placed in the `Add` menu of the project by default).

```
<Commands>
    <Button guid="your-command-set" 
            id="cmdIdAddItemHelloWorld" priority="0x1100" type="Button">
        <Parent guid="your-command-set" id="grpIdProjectContextAdd" />
        <Strings>
            <ButtonText>Hello World</ButtonText>
        </Strings>
    </Button>
</Commands>
```

To make the button also appear in the `Add` menu of the solution node, I use a command placement...

```
<CommandPlacements>
    <CommandPlacement guid="your-command-set" 
                      id="cmdIdAddItemHelloWorld" priority="0x1100">
        <Parent guid="your-command-set" id="grpIdSolutionContextAdd" />
    </CommandPlacement>
 </CommandPlacements>
```

For me, it feels a bit hacky to use the `cmdidShellWindowNavigate7` and `cmdidShellWindowNavigate5` 
constants, but in the result I got this...

[image]

Comment: can you please provide a link to file with example code?

Comment: Thank you @Matze, this was really helpfull.
I would like to find some documentation about vsct, as i still don't get how did you found the "cmdidShellWindowNavigate7" was actually the "Project" Add menu