# In VS Solution Explorer, how to extend right click menus on source files sub code elements (class/method/field)

Tags: visual-studio, menu, vsix, solution-explorer

I am developing a Visual Studio Extension (VSIX).

I need to add custom right-click menus on Solution Explorer right click of class/methods/fields items, that can be found under source file items:

[image]

In the .vsct file I already extend the Solution Explorer *project/folder/source file/reference* right click menus this way:

```
<CommandPlacement guid="guidNDepend_PackageCmdSet" id="grpSolutionExplorer" priority="0x100">
  <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_ITEMNODE" />
</CommandPlacement>
<CommandPlacement guid="guidNDepend_PackageCmdSet" id="grpSolutionExplorer" priority="0x100">
  <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_PROJNODE" />
</CommandPlacement>
<CommandPlacement guid="guidNDepend_PackageCmdSet" id="grpSolutionExplorer" priority="0x100">
  <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_FOLDERNODE" />
</CommandPlacement>
<CommandPlacement guid="guidNDepend_PackageCmdSet" id="grpSolutionExplorer" priority="0x100">
  <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_REFERENCE" />
</CommandPlacement>
```

I tried all other values I have found without success:

```
IDM_VS_CTXT_CODEWIN
IDM_VS_CTXT_XPROJ_MULTIITEM
IDM_VS_CTXT_XPROJ_PROJITEM
IDM_VS_CTXT_NOCOMMANDS
IDM_VS_CTXT_REFERENCEROOT
```

Thanks for your help.

(Notice that I already have tricky code to resolve the right-clicked code element, invoked from `IVsSelectionEvents.OnSelectionChanged()`, just before `QueryStatus()` handlers are fired)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See:

[Using EnableVSIPLogging to identify menus and commands with VS 2005 + SP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dr._ex/archive/2007/04/17/using-enablevsiplogging-to-identify-menus-and-commands-with-vs-2005-sp1.aspx)

and:

[How to find Command GUID:ID pairs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/martintracy/archive/2006/05/23/604927.aspx)

---

Thanks Carlos, I made this work :) So let's explain a bit. First as explained in the blog post I setup the regkey:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\General]
"EnableVSIPLogging"=dword:00000001
```

Then re-starded VS2013, hold Ctrl+SHIFT and right click a file-content class in the SlnExplorer Window. I got this:

[image]

The Guid is the `guidSHLMainMenu` one, but I needed to get the command ID from the value `1842` (`0x0732` in hexadecimal). I googled a bit and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26928566/27194). I had VS2013 SDK installed. I looked for where was located the header file `vsshlids.h`. It was in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Inc
```

In this directory I did a search on any text file that contains `732`. And I found

```
#define IDM_VS_CTXT_PROJWIN_FILECONTENTS            0x732  // Context menu for GraphNode items in the Solution Explorer
```

in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Inc\vsshlids.h
```

Hence the name I was looking for is **IDM_VS_CTXT_PROJWIN_FILECONTENTS** and indeed with this value it works like a charm; Thanks Carlos!

Comment: Both links are invalid by now (but it's not your fault). :) But thanks for your help.

For VS2017 I needed to additionally in regedit, I've selected HKEY_USERS, File > Load Hive, selected file:

"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_effa0b41Exp\privateregistry.bin"

typed as vs2017_exp, and selected registry branch:

HKEY_USERS\vs2017_exp\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_effa0b41Exp\General

Otherwise works identically.